# Do I need Fate Core to make Fate Accelerated Edition work?

Tags: fate-core, fate-accelerated

I have recently been looking into the Fate "universe" and would like to know, do you need Fate Core to actually play Fate Accelerated Edition?

Answer (score 16):

No, you don't.

Anyway, even if that was the case, their [SRD](http://fate-srd.com/) contain the complete rules of both games.

[heatenJesus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3178/heathenjesus) informs me that sometimes the FAE rules points at the Fate Core rules "for more detail".

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered!

Comment: @Cristopher I got pinged by your comment because I'm the author of the answer but Elijah won't, unless you ping him with "@nickname"-

Comment: @ElijahLovesRpg ping! Don't forget to mark as answered  ^_^

Comment: While this is definitely true, I feel compelled to note that many parts of the FAE rules basically default to "for more detail, see so-and-so section of the Fate Core rules". FAE is a standalone game, but the FAE rulebook... less so

Comment: _"for more detail, see so-and-so section of the Fate Core rules"_. FAE is like a cookbook that shows you how to make a certain meal, whereas Fate Core is a chef who talks you through the decisions that led to the making of that meal.